# Router RedirectTo default does not fire event NavigationEnd

Tags: angular, angular6, router

I am using Angular v6.1.0 and. My routing file here:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'activity', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'activity', component: ActivityComponent },
      { path: 'recent-activity', component: RecentActivityComponent },
      { path: 'notification', component: NotificationComponent }
    ]
  },

];
```

And here is my code to subscribe navigation events:

```
router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // Do something here
      } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // Do something here
      }
    });
```

When I use router.navigation the NavigationEnd is fired.
But If I go to **/dashboard** router and it will redirect to **/dashboard/activity** in above routing file, the event does not fired.

**UPDATE**
Here is my example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-fm4n71) 
Just enter the domain without any path, the console only log '/' when redirect to login (I prefer to log '/login')

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xujxuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) Can you create a StackBlitz to demonstrate the issue please?

Comment: Yeah, I see my mistake. Thanks for your StackBlitz demo, so useful for me :)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, with Angular 6.1.X. Anyone figured out how to fix?

Comment: @BrunoBruzzano You can use **event.urlAfterRedirects** instead of **event.url** as StackBlitz sample above.

Comment: Since the StackBlitz link no longer works, I wanted to clarify this one since I ran into the same issue. The event.urlAfterRedirects field will be populated for NavigationEnd events, but not NavigationStart. The value will be to the final url instead of the initial one that gets redirected.